# Как изменить цвет шрифта или фона кнопки в QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qss, qmessagebox

При работе с *PyQt5* возникла проблема. Дело в том, что при работе на *Windows* возникла необходимость поменять цвет кнопок в `QMessageBox`.

Подскажете пожалуйста, как можно обратится  кнопке и задать ей `stylesheet`? 
Если это невозможно, то как можно задать ей цвет шрифта или фона при добавлении кнопки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется стандартная кнопка **`ok`** и ее цвет не устраивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте следующий stylesheet и установите цвет который вам нужен

```
setStyleSheet("QMessageBox QPushButton { color: white; background-color: green; }");
```

Более подробный пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, qApp, QMessageBox

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 200)
        button = QPushButton('Click me', self)
        qApp.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox QPushButton{background-color: Silver;}")
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Notification', 'Text', QMessageBox.Ok) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = App()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не могли бы вы подсказать где это написано в документации, или где это можно узнать в подобных ситуациях?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html